# updating array in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : 1,            
    "Accounts" : [ 
                {
                    "Date" : ISODate("2015-04-10T05:29:46.362Z"),
                    "Total_Debits" : 0,
                    "Total_Credits" : 0
                }
            ]
}




BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject();
search.put("_id", id);
search.put("Accounts.Date", date);
accounts.put("Total_Debits", total_Fp_Dr);
accounts.put("Total_Credits", total_Fp_Cr);
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update1put("$push", new  BasicDBObject("Accounts.$.Total_Debits",total_Fp_Dr));
                        accountHeads.update(search,update)
```

Comment: Sorry i did't placed my problem...problem is i'm not able to update above document plz help me...thank you

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: @San Instead of commenting you can edit your question!

Comment: some formatting problem so....i'm not able to post so...

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your queries as follows:

```
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id", id).append("Date", date);
DBObject accountsArray = new BasicDBObject("Accounts", 
                             new BasicDBObject("Date", date)
                                .append("Total_Debits", total_Fp_Dr)
                                .append("Total_Credits", total_Fp_Cr));

DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$push", accountsArray);
accountHeads.update(searchQuery, updateQuery);
```

Comment: means i need update document using id and date .....so id and date are search queries

Comment: @San Updated the answer to include the date query.

Comment: @San What's not working? Can you at least be more explicit with your question? As it is, it's pretty hard to tell what you are trying to achieve, how your document is currently structured, where are the variable values in your query and update coming from etc? Be precise about your problem by providing a minimal bug-demonstrating test case, just enough code to exhibit the undesirable behaviour and no more.